# jquery: Datatables.net change paginationtype based on different filter

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using jquery plugin datatables.net.

I want to change the pagination type of already initialized datatable. The pagination should change based on the some filter that user selects. I tried by reinitializing the datatable by changing the "sPaginationType" property to a new value but i

initialize code

```
datatableGrid = $('#datagrid').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

code onclick of a filter button:

```
datatableGrid.fnDestroy();
datatableGrid = $('#datagrid').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "two_button"
});
```

The above code is throwing a javascript error for invisble columns.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Please guide me which way I can achieve the functionality for changing the gridpagination style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the pagination style for an existing dataTable by using [fnSettings](https://datatables.net/ref#fnSettings) and some javascript.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluegeek9bluegeek9/Ekp28/)

```
$('.dataTables_paginate > span').remove();
$('.dataTables_paginate > a:nth-child(3)').remove();
$('.dataTables_paginate > a:nth-child(3)').remove();


datatableGrid.fnSettings().sPaginationType = "two_button";
datatableGrid.fnDraw(false);
```